# How to make JavaScript count only in a specific DIV tag

Tags: javascript

I have this code that counts the select boxes chosen that equal 5. how do i only make it count the selects in

```
<div id="groupa">
```

Here is the code i have

```
function getSelectedValues(){
var matches = $('select').filter(function(){
return $(this).val() == '5';
}).length;
// here's where we just update that new <span>
$('span#result5').text(matches);
}
```

Comment: How is the question related to Java?

Comment: `$('#groupa select').filter(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your selector

```
function getSelectedValues(){
var matches = $('#groupa select').filter(function(){
return $(this).val() == '5';
}).length;
// here's where we just update that new <span>
$('span#result5').text(matches);
}
```